# Move elements from one array to another and display value of both arrays at the same time

Tags: javascript, arrays

(Javascript) How do I move elements from one array to another in random order on click of a button and also display elements in both the arrays at the same time?

For example the desired output is :

Elements in array1 : 1,2,3,4,5

Elements in array2 : -

**BUTTON**

now on clicking the button

Elements in array1 : 1,2,4,5

Elements in array2 : 3

**BUTTON**

now on clicking the button

Elements in array1 : 2,4,5

Elements in array2 : 3,1

**BUTTON**

now on clicking the button

Elements in array1 : 2,5

Elements in array2 : 3,1,4

**BUTTON**

and so on...

This is what i got from another stackoverflow user.

```js
let array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
document.getElementById("btn").onclick = () => { 
  let num = array1[Math.floor(Math.random()*array1.length)]
  const index = array1.indexOf(num); 
  if (index > -1) {
     array1.splice(index, 1); 
     alert("You chose: " + num + "\nArray: " + array1)
  } else {
    alert("No numbers remaining.") 
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="btn">Get Random Number</button>
```

Comment: I am a beginner so would appreciate explanation in //comments

Comment: What exactly have you tried so far?

Comment: The main purpose of this site is to help people fix problems with code they already have written, not to provide extended tutorials.

Comment: @sesamechicken this is what i got from a user on stackoverflow  
let array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
document.getElementById("btn").onclick = () => { 
  let num = array1[Math.floor(Math.random()*array1.length)]
  const index = array1.indexOf(num); 
  if (index > -1) {
     array1.splice(index, 1); 
     alert("You chose: " + num + "\nArray: " + array1)
  } else {
    alert("No numbers remaining.") 
  }
}

Comment: Please don't post extended codes in comments, that is hard to read. Add it to your question, and format it properly - https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: @CBroe Added the code to the question

Comment: So you got most of it already ... Now add the `num` value to a second array, and then display them both. (And for how to display them, you can do a bit more research, if you still don't have any idea on that.)

Comment: @CBroe i improvised the code a little by adding 
 `let array2 = [num]`
   but this stores the value of only the spliced number in the array and displays only the most recently spliced number. How do i store and display the value of all the spliced numbers in the array?

Comment: Initialize array2 as an empty array before, and then _add_ new items to it. (Both are very basics things, so if you don't know how - go research it, please.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you were basically there. The below gets an element in the dom via ID and sets the text value to the array you're adding to. You can run the code snippet below to see what's going on. Good luck !

```js
const arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
const arr2 = []

const doThing = () => {
  // get the random position
  const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr1.length);
  
  // push the random index to the second array
  arr2.push(arr1[index])
  
  // remove the randome index from arr1
  arr1.splice(index, 1)
  
  // show it
  const display = document.getElementById('array')
  display.innerText = arr2.toString()
  
  // log both out so you can see what's happening
  console.log(arr1, arr2)
}
```

```html
<button onClick=doThing()>clicky</button>
<span id='array' />
```

Comment: Thanks!! I was having trouble with displaying the array elements and still having the button present there. This solves it!

Comment: Nice! You might want to mark it as the answer for future searchers!